# Exclude all subcategories in the_category (post)

Tags: categories, exclude

I'm looking for a way to hide all the subcategories based in my post:

It always displays in my posts like : Categorie, sub categories.

So I'd like to exclude all of the sub_categories.

I've been trying to trick this portion of code:

```
<?php the_category(', ') ?>
```

but I can not manage to make it work .

If anybody has a solution, I ll be really thankful!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no filter for [`the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category). All that `the_category` does is to `echo` `get_the_category_list`. Have a look at the function in *wp-includes/category-template.php* lines 273 - 275

```
273 function the_category( $separator = '', $parents='', $post_id = false ) {
274         echo get_the_category_list( $separator, $parents, $post_id );
275 }
```

Personally I would say that `the_category` is incorrect for what you want to do, as you don't need to display any type of parent/child relationship

You can take a look at [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) which gives you a lot of flexibility. `wp_list_categories` is also not just limited to categories, is can be used for custom taxonomies as well.

The parameter that you should have a look at here is `depth` which you can set to

- 0 - All Categories and child Categories (Default).
- 1 - All Categories displayed in flat (no indent) form (overrides hierarchical).
- 1 - Show only top level Categories
- n - Value of n (some number) specifies the depth (or level) to descend in displaying Categories

Here is a slightly modified version of the code found in the codex page. I've set the `depth` parameter to `1`, which will only show the top most category level

```
<?php 
$taxonomy = 'category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&depth=1&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```